# Fibonacci numbers and binary integers

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

Well I got it from a competitive exam paper from 2012.
$$
{  }
$$
Let $a_n$ be the number of all $n$ - digit positive integers formed by digits $0,1$ or both such that no consecutive digits in them are $0$. Let $b_n =$ number of such integers ending with $1$ and  $c_n =$ number of such integers ending with $0$. 
$$
{  }
$$
Then I made a table:
$$1$$
$$10,11$$
$$101, 110, 111$$
$$1010, 1011, 1101, 1110, 1111$$
$$10101, 10110, 10111, 11010, 11011, 11110, 11111$$
$$....\text {etc.} $$
While $c_n=F_n$ is clearly the Fibonacci sequence, $b_n=F_{n+1}$ and $a_n=F_{n+2}$. How? Is there a way to prove it? I thought perhaps we could use combinatorics but, just a thought, no way out. Any help/suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: There are many duplicates.  Searching for binary consecutive will find many of them.

Comment: @Ross Millikan , thanks for help.